# On top vs on the top vs at the top

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, grammaticality-in-context, prepositional-phrases, conversation

Which preposition to use to describe the following:

1-Countries which are weak will become on top .

2-Countries which are weak will become on the top.

3- Counntries which are weak will become at the top.

Comment: All three expressions (_on top_, _on the top_, and _at the top_) are grammatical, with different meanings. None of them collocate with _become_. What you mean, I think, is either _will come out on top_ or _will get to the top_. These two are not the same: _on top_ means "on top of all others", whereas _at/to the top_ means "among those at the top, not necessarily above them all".

Comment: @Colin Fine  Thank you for the explanation. So can I say "They will be on top", "on the top" ,"at the top"